# Can't configure node_chat to localhost

Tags: node.js

I went to configure server.js but I get the error connecting to server.

HOST=localhost;
PORT= 80;

http://github.com/ry/node_chat

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different port. I believe node.js has some trouble listening on port 80